# Naming a log DB table

Tags: database-design, logging, naming

I have a DB table that stores log messages and I need a name for it.

It has to be plural and preferably - a single word.

Perhaps some of you have worked with logging frameworks and you can share the names they use.

Comment: No, but is it correct? My understanding is that `log` (singular) means a list of logged messages. If that is so, `logs` (plural) would mean multiple lists of logged messages and that is not correct as the DB table is a single list.

Comment: I, personally, think of `a log` as a single message aswell

Comment: It depends on what you are logging. If the set of messages belongs to a single type, then perhaps `Log` is right, if however you are using the table for multiple purposes, `Logs` is more appropriate. IIS for example logs into a `Logs` directory (one log file per site).

Comment: @BenV, I really like `events`. I wish you had suggested it in an answer rather than a comment.

Comment: @Emanuil: It's an answer now :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I've also seen `Events` used for this purpose.